# Renaming "key" in map using `Dart`

Tags: json, dart, dictionary, object

My intention is to format the name `key` in an existing Map value.
Supposed the current `key` value is in `UpperCase` but I wanted to make it `LowerCase`

From this

```dart
Map<String, String> foo = {
       "A" : "valueOne", 
       "B" : "valueTwo",
};

print(foo); // output: {"A" : "valueOne", "B" : "valueTwo"}
```

To this

```dart
print(foo); // output: {"a" : "valueOne", "b" : "valueTwo"}
```

Here's the method I tried:

```dart
Map<String, String> foo = {
       "A" : "valueOne", 
       "B" : "valueTwo",
};

foo.forEach((key, value) {
    key = key.toString().toLowerCase();
    value = value;
});

... something something
```

also tried to assign the `forEach` as a value

```dart
Map<String, String> foo = {
       "A" : "valueOne", 
       "B" : "valueTwo",
};

var bar = foo.forEach((key, value) {
    key = key.toString().toLowerCase();
    value = value;
});

print(bar); // Failed because forEach Datatype is `void`

... something something
```

also tried

```dart
Map<String, String> foo = {
       "A" : "valueOne", 
       "B" : "valueTwo",
};

foo.forEach((key, value) {
    key = key.toString().toLowerCase();
    value = value;

    Map<String, String> bar = {key: value};

    print(bar); // `Output: {a: valueOne} {b: valueTwo}` <- is not what I was looking for.
});

... something something
```

Any suggestions on what to do Next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot *change* a key, you have to remove the old key and add a new key instead.

You can then choose to either update the existing map, or build a new one.

Creating a new one is simpler:

```dart
var newMap = {for (var e in oldMap.entries) e.key.toLowerCase() : e.value};
```

We ignore the risk of having existing keys which are equal after calling `toLowerCase`, like `"Foo"`, `"FOO"` and `"foo"`.

Updating the existing map is trickier, but if we ignore the same risks, it can be something like:

```dart
// Snapshot the keys to avoid concurrent modification error when iterating.
for (var e in map.entries.toList()) { 
  var key = e.key;
  var lc = key.toLowerCase();
  if (lc != key) {
    map[lc] = e.value;
    map.remove(key); 
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use a [CanonicalizedMap](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/CanonicalizedMap-class.html) to begin with, which does the lower-casing for you (and allows you to look up with any casing of the same text).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already.

```dart
  Map<String, String> foo = {
    "A": "valueOne",
    "B": "valueTwo",
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> bar = {};

  foo.keys.toList().forEach((key) {
    bar.addAll({key.toString().toLowerCase(): foo[key]});
  });

  print(bar);
}
```